# Странные подключение в ec2

Tags: python, nginx, docker, amazon-web-services, uwsgi

Я задеплоил мои модели на ec2, и начал получать странные подключения:

```
[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 17/17] 3.0.182.215 () {40 vars in 608 bytes} [Sat Jan 23 19:36:40 2021] POST / => generated 178 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 405) 3 headers in 123 bytes 
(1 switches on core 0)
15.207.221.143 - - [23/Jan/2021:19:44:27 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 18/18] 15.207.221.143 () {36 vars in 504 bytes} [Sat Jan 23 19:44:27 2021] GET /.env => generated 232 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 87 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
15.207.221.143 - - [23/Jan/2021:19:44:27 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 19/19] 15.207.221.143 () {40 vars in 611 bytes} [Sat Jan 23 19:44:27 2021] POST / => generated 178 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 405) 3 headers in 123 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
102.165.30.37 - - [23/Jan/2021:19:45:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 225 "-" "NetSystemsResearch studies the availability of various services across the internet. Our website is netsystemsresearch.com" "-"
```

Особенно последнее.
Так же я обнаружил три новых файла в корневой папке, которых раньше не было:

```
core.10 core.19 core.29
```

Их можно удалить, но нельзя посмотреть или скопировать.

Приложение базируется на tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-docker

Код тут: https://github.com/Tayge/demonstration_models

Откуда взялись эти файлы, чем грозят эти подключения? Насколько я понял это проверка портов для прокси. Можно ли как-то защитить свой сервер?